# Finder - how to search for all files without a tag

Tags: finder

In Finder there is a way to show all files with a certain colour tag (see screenshot below).

[image: screenshot of finder tag search]

But is there a way in Finder to search for all files:

- a) without a tag
- b) with a tag of any colour (eg. any tag)

Im running OSX 10.13.x

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUsyf.png Click "other" to see all options

Comment: @anki where how do i get to that menu in your screenshot ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wySGL.png